# How to create sample data for this Code and input inside the .cpp file to just run It and get results?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding

I have this cpp Code.
How can I create a sample data and input directly in this file to just run It and get expected results?

This is an path-finder algorithm to find shortest and more profitable pairs path.

```
#include "readGraph.hpp"
#include "ShortestPath.hpp"
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    ifstream fin(argv[1]);
    ofstream fout(argv[2]);

    double cost = atof(argv[5]);

    int** edgeL;
    double* weights;

    int numEdges;
    double totalDist;

    string* e; //eLabels
    string* v; //vLabels

    /* edgeList version of readGraph */
    int numVertices = readGraph(fin,edgeL,weights,numEdges,v, e);

    string sourceV = argv[3];
    string destV = argv[4];

    /* Checking input source and destination vertices and assigning their corresponding integer values */ 
    int source, dest;
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i ++){
        if(sourceV == v[i]){
            source = i;
        }
        if(destV == v[i]){
            dest = i; 
        }
    }
    
    int* prev;
    double* dist;
    int* path;
    int* cycle;

    /*Prepping the weights for bellmanFord by taking setting w[i] = -log(temp*(1-cost)) */
    for(int i = 0; i < numEdges; i ++){
        double temp = weights[i];
        weights[i] = -1*log(temp*(1-cost));
        cout << weights[i] << endl;
    }
    
    /* Setting timers and invoking bellmanFord to catch arbitrage opportunity */
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int x = bellmanFord(edgeL, weights, numVertices, numEdges, source, dist, prev);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto dur = t2-t1;
    auto durns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(dur);
    double elapsed = durns.count();
    
   
    /** If there is a negative loop, there is an arbitrage opportunity.
     *  A path is derived using the appropriate getCycle method. 
     *  The path is printed to fout and meta data printed to the terminal.
    */
    if(x != -1){
        int cycleSize = getCycle(x, prev, numVertices, cycle);
        fout << numVertices << " " << cycleSize << endl;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i ++){
            fout << v[i] << endl;
        }
        
        int idx = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cycleSize; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numEdges; j ++){
                if(edgeL[j][0] == cycle[i] && edgeL[j][1] == cycle[i+1]){
                    totalDist += weights[j];
                    fout << cycle[i] << " " << cycle[i+1] << " " << exp(-1*weights[j]) << " " << e[j] << endl;
                    idx = j;
                }
            }
        }
        
        cout << "Arbitrage Opportunity Detected!" << endl;
        cout << "Effective Exchange Rate: " << exp(-1*totalDist) << endl;
        cout << "Runtime: " << elapsed << " Microseconds" << endl;

    delete[] cycle;
    for (int i=0; i<numEdges; i++){
        delete[] edgeL[i];
    }
    }

    /** If there is no negative cycle. 
     *  The path is simply printed to fout and meta data printed to terminal. 
     */
    else if(x == -1){

    int pathSize = getPath(source, dest, prev, path);
    fout << numVertices << " " << pathSize - 1 << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++){
        fout << v[i] << endl;
    }
    
    int temp;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < pathSize-1; i++){
        temp = path[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < numEdges; j ++){
            if(edgeL[j][0] == path[i] && edgeL[j][1] == path[i+1]){
                totalDist += weights[j];
                fout << temp << " " << path[i+1] << " " << exp(-1*weights[j]) << " " << e[j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Effective Exchange Rate: " << exp(-1*totalDist) << endl;
    cout << "Runtime: " << elapsed << " " << "Microseconds" << endl;

    delete[] path;
    for (int i=0; i<numEdges; i++){
        delete[] edgeL[i];
    }    
    }

    delete[] dist;
    delete[] prev;
    delete[] e;
    delete[] v;
    delete[] weights;
    delete[] edgeL;

}
```

This is an example of data, but how to input inside the same file.

Sample data 1:

```
 6 1


GBP


EUR


JPY


CHF


USD


GLD


0 1 1.45543 GBP->EUR
```

Sample data 2:

```
6 30

GBP

EUR

JPY

CHF

USD

GLD

0 1 1.4599 GBP->EUR

0 2 189.05 GBP->JPY

0 3 2.1904 GBP->CHF

0 4 1.5714 GBP->USD

0 5 0.004816 GBP->GLD

1 0 0.684978 EUR->GBP

1 2 129.52 EUR->JPY

1 3 1.4978 EUR->CHF

1 4 1.0752 EUR->USD

1 5 0.003295 EUR->GLD

2 0 0.00528961 JPY->GBP

2 1 0.00772082 JPY->EUR

2 3 0.011574 JPY->CHF

2 4 0.008309 JPY->USD

2 5 0.0000255 JPY->GLD

3 0 0.456538 CHF->GBP

3 1 0.667646 CHF->EUR

3 2 86.4006 CHF->JPY

3 4 0.7182 CHF->USD

3 5 0.002201 CHF->GLD

4 0 0.636375 USD->GBP

4 1 0.93006 USD->EUR

4 2 120.351 USD->JPY

4 3 1.39237 USD->CHF

4 5 0.003065 USD->GLD

5 0 207.641 GLD->GBP

5 1 303.49 GLD->EUR

5 2 39215.7 GLD->JPY

5 3 454.339 GLD->CHF

5 4 326.264 GLD->USD
```

Ive still not tried any option because I don't know how to create this array.

Comment: I'd have created several classes for this.
One class that manages and hold your input data, this way you only have to modify this class API to add or remove new data.
Then, one class for each kind of data you have. Here, this would be 2 classes : one for GBP strings for example, and the other one to manage 3 2 86.4006 CHF->JPY data.
Your high level class would take a stream as input and will be responsible to parse your file to assign each instances of the 2 data classes you'd have. This high level class shall have data structure to ease the data management, e.g. a std::vector

Comment: The readGraph should be designed agnostic if it gets std::ifstream (for what you need file) or std::stringstream (that you can initialize in code) so there are no obvious problems.

Comment: " I don't know how to create this array."  What array are you referring to?  Do you want to know how to declare or populate your array?  You should use std::vector rather than an array - it makes all this much easier and less error prone.  Why does you sample input contain so many empty lines?  Why do you declare everything in the main routine - do you not know how to design classes?   Bottom line, this code is so badly designed that it is really not worthwhile trying to "fix" it.  Suggest you start again by designing a graph class.